# Stuck on a partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I read some stuff about partial derivative. If I understood correctly, partial derivative is when you consider all other variables as constant and independent and total derivative is when you dont consider them constant, you consider the direct or indirect contribution of every variable.

But here I have those functions and I don't know how to deal with them :

$\epsilon = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$

$f(x, \sigma, \mu) = log(\sigma) - (\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})^{2}$

I want to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \sigma}$

Should I consider $(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})^{2}$ as a constant because its equal to epsilon, or not ? I am confused, if someone could explain to me

Comment: Forget about $\epsilon = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma},$ it is irrelevant in the definition of $f.$ $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \sigma}(x,\sigma,\mu)=\frac1\sigma+2\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^3}.$

Comment: If you wanted $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon}$ you would have an issue though.

Comment: Is your $\log$ $\ln$? If it have some base, i.e. you have $\log_a$, then this affects derivative.

Comment: Yes its ln for the log, e basis. I don't understand why ∂/∂ would cause a problem ? Shouldnt I just apply use the epsilon formula and inject it in f, then derive ?